# Earth, water, air, and Fire

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Earth, water, air, and Fire
>
> All of these, and some are higher
>
> Staffs and goblets, swords and gold,
>
> Who knows what the future holds?
>
> Twenty two steps in the journey you take
>
> Death isn't the end, it's only a break.
>
> What might I be? It isn't that hard
>
> The answer as always is all in the cards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you

> A Tarot deck?

Staffs and goblets, swords and gold

> Suits are Staves, Cups, Swords, and Coins

Who knows what the future holds?

> Used for prognostication

Twenty two steps in the journey you take

> 22 Major Arcana

Death isn't the end, it's only a break.

> 1 of which is Death

The answer as always is all in the cards.

> It's a deck of cards

Comment: the last line made it too easy didn't it! Ack I always do that. Good job getting most of the clues! The first line was in reference to the fact that the suits are associaed with the four elements with pentacles = earth, cups = water, swords = air, and wands = fire. The 'journey' line was a direct reference to The Fool's Journey from card 0, the Fool to card 21, the World.

Comment: @MMAdams I was thinking Tarot from about the fourth line (about the suits telling the future) so I'm not sure the last line was a particularly big giveaway.

Comment: @mmadams I had it in mind by "Staffs and goblets, swords and gold," but some of my all time favorite riddles are a bit easy, especially for people that frequent this site.  I loved this one (+1) and I'd have been proud as hell if I'd come up with it.  I'll be memorizing it as best I can.

Comment: What about the first and second lines, with the elements?

Comment: @BrentHackers oh my gosh thank you for this comment, you made my day